# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Tags: json, spring-data-jpa, jackson, spring-data, jackson-databind

Below method is throwing this error

```
private void saveTableAndColumns(Map<String, Object> record, Long dbID) {
        TypeReference<DatabaseTable> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() {};
        String json = JsonUtil.toJson(record); // return json string
        try {
            DatabaseTable databaseTable = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
            System.out.println(databaseTable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My Model

```
public class DatabaseTable extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("readable_table_name")
    @Column(name = "readable_table_name")
    private String readableTableName;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Transient
    private boolean open;

    @Transient
    private boolean expandable;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonProperty("database_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "database_id", nullable = false)
    private Database database;

    @JsonProperty("columns")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TableColumn> columns;
}
```

JsonUtil

```
public class JsonUtil {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    }

    public static <T> String toJson(T obj) {
        try{
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String string, Class<T> _class) {
        try{
            return mapper.readValue(string, _class);
        }catch ( Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T> HashMap<String,Object> toMap(T obj) {
        return mapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        });
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> toArray(T obj) {
        return mapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>>() {
        });
    }

    public static <T> T fromMap(Map<String,Object> map , TypeReference<T> t) {
        return mapper.convertValue(map, t);
    }
}
```

record map

```
{table_schema=public, table_catalog=diamond, table_name="public"."rules_engine_permissions", columns=[{"name":"id","data_type":"bigint"}, 
 {"name":"role_id","data_type":"bigint"}, 
 {"name":"name","data_type":"integer"}, 
 {"name":"created_at","data_type":"timestamp without time zone"}, 
 {"name":"updated_at","data_type":"timestamp without time zone"}], readable_table_name=rules_engine_permissions}
```

I am consistently getting this error can you please help what is the issue and what I may be missing.
This is the exception text
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.thehighpaudel.fairmont.ui.model.TableColumn>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
at [Source: (String)"{"table_schema":"public","table_catalog":"diamond","table_name":""public"."schema_migrations"","columns":{"type":"json","value":"[{"name":"version","data_type":"character varying"}]","null":true},"readable_table_name":"schema_migrations"}"; line: 1, column: 110] (through reference chain: com.thehighpaudel.fairmont.ui.model.DatabaseTable["columns"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Comment: Is the string exception message correct ? Because for example instead of `,` you have `.` after `public`.

Comment: yes that is whole value  "public"."rules_engine_permissions" and correct, the issue is with the columns key